# When using checkbox I get Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Tags: c#

I am using a simple checkbox and everything works fine on my development machine but the end user is getting

> "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32".

I tried varying the code with the same result. My machine is running Windows 8.1 and the end user is on Windows Server 2008 R2.

First I tried this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    this.personnelBindingSource.Filter = ("License =" + arg); 
}
```

next I tried this,

```
string checkRelated = checkBox1.CheckState.ToString();

if(checkRelated.Equals("Unchecked"))
{
    this.personnelBindingSource.Filter = ("License =" + arg);
}
```

I don't see why it even thinks I am using the '=' operation. Does anyone know why I am getting the error?

EDIT: I had this in the code.

```
    InitializeComponent();
    myArgLicense = "'" + myArgLicense + "'";
```

The above was not a global change so I was not interpreting the scope right in my checkbox routine. I changed the code to Sachu's recommendation it worked fine.

```
    if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            this.personnelBindingSource.Filter = ("License =" + "'" + myArgLicense + "'"); 
        }
```

Comment: What type is `personnelBindingSource`? I presume `.Filter` is of type `Int32` which is why you are getting the incompatible datatype error. Maybe `arg` is of type `Int32` and so it cannot be concationated with the `string` which could cause this error too. Please post more details.

Comment: There missing parts in your question, what is the type of the ׳Filter׳ property and the ׳arg׳ parameter?

Comment: You will need to check on the exact value of arg during runtime. The parenthesis are superfluos but not the problem. Concatenating strings with numbers is fine, too.. for those who wonder: [BindingSource.Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a string - What line exactly is throwing the error??

Comment: try with arg.tostring().. or try this.personnelBindingSource.Filter = ("License = ' " + arg + " ' ");

Comment: Never, ever write code like this `if(checkRelated.Equals("Unchecked"))`. Enums are there to provide some type-safety against invalid values, don't trash it away by convertying everything to string. Back to the topic, which framework are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could be interpreted as int32 is arg, so I would try this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    this.personnelBindingSource.Filter = ("License ='" + arg.ToString() + "'"); 
}
```

EDIT: I saw Sachu's comment too late.